# How do I use the pthreads in a ROS C++ Node

Tags: c++, pthreads, ros

I am trying to use pthread library inside the ros Node, I am including it as `#include <pthread>`. When I run `catkin_make` I get the error below. I created a simple thread as `std::thread m1(move, 1);`

```
thread: No such file or directory
 #include <pthread>
          ^~~~~~~~~
```

The signature of the move function is `void move(short axis_no, short direction = 0)` and I instantiated the thread as

```
std::thread m1(move, 1);    
m1.join();
```

I tried to add the pthread library in my CmakeLists.txt as follows
`add_compile_options(-std=c++11 -pthread)` and
`target_link_libraries(pthread)`. Is there a way I can use the pthread library inside the ros Node?

Thank you.

Comment: `pthread.h` perhaps? But you probably want `<thread>`

Comment: There is no `pthread` header; there is `pthread.h`. Second, if you're using a compliant C++11 toolchain, why you would use pthreads directly is a mystery, since `<thread>` offers a rich feature set to absolve you of the `pthread.h` madness.

Comment: Is using pthreads directly in a modern C++ (C++11 or later) program copacetic?

Comment: `#include <thread>` then your code `std::thread m1(move, 1);` looks OK. If you use CMake, then `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)` ; if you want to tell gcc to use pthread library, then it is `-lpthread`

Comment: I included `thread` and i get the error
```/usr/include/c++/7/thread:240:2: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(short int, short int)> >::_M_invoke(std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(short int, short int)> >::_Indices)’
  operator()()
```

Comment: Please make a [mre]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pthread` is a C library available on some platforms and if you want to use the `pthread_*` functions you need to `#include <pthread.h>`.

Since C++11 there is an abstraction layer on top of the native threading libraries which is available if you instead `#include <thread>`.

You can then use `std::thread` - but you will still need to link with `-pthread`.

Instead of hardcoding `-pthread`, you can let `CMake` find and add the appropriate library:

```
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(your_app PRIVATE Threads::Threads)
```

---

In your program, the `move` function needs two arguments (the function signature is `void(*)(short, short)` even if you have a default value for `direction`).

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void move(short axis_no, short direction = 0) {
    std::cout << axis_no << ' ' << direction << '\n';
}

int main() {
    auto th = std::thread(move, 1, 2); // needs 2 arguments
    th.join();
}
```

If you want, you can create an overload to only have to supply one argument, but in that case you also need to help the compiler to select the correct overload.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void move(short axis_no, short direction) { // no default value here
    std::cout << axis_no << ' ' << direction << '\n';
}

void move(short axis_no) { // proxy function
    move(axis_no, 0);      // where 0 is default
}

int main() {
    using one = void(*)(short);
    using two = void(*)(short, short);

    // use one of the above type aliases to select the proper overload:
    auto th = std::thread(static_cast<one>(move), 1);
    th.join();
}
```

Comment: I am getting the error ```usr/include/c++/7/thread:240:2: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(short int, short int), int> >::_M_invoke(std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(short int, short int), int> >::_Indices)’
  operator()()
  ^~~~~~~~
``` I do not know what could be wrong

Comment: Hello Ted, I just updated the question to include that

Comment: @daRula Ah... the function actually requires _2_ arguments

Comment: Wow, thank you Ted, I thought because the other variable was default, it was not necessary. It worked

Comment: Also for some reason when I remove the Lines 
```find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(your_app PRIVATE Threads::Threads)
``` 
from CmakeList.txt it still compiles

Comment: @daRula You're welcome. Well, it may be cached. Clean and regenerate with `cmake`.